# Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple VS2015

Tags: android, ios, mobile

It is my first time to develop a mobile app using visual studio 
this is what I have done:

- creating a new crodova app
- build the project
- run it

when running it I get the following error message:

> "Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple"

I have found solutions while searching through the website, but none of them worked. one of the solutions was to delete solution .suo files. Open Solution .sln. But where to find the solution .suo ??? I could not find it.

please I need help, and sorry if the question is not presented well, but as I said I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved !
it was just because the Chrome was denied by the admin

Comment: Hi, what did you do to "undeny" Chrome?

Comment: it supposed that you have to share the solution if you have it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Go to project properties, open **"Configuration Manager..."** and then check **"Deploy"** for **"Debug"** configuration.

[image]